# Building COM Objects in C# - how to pass generic types (List)?

Tags: c#, .net, com

I'm a newbie to .net, and I'm trying to connect VB6 to C# by creating a COM callable object
in C# (I'm using this awesome [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3511/Exposing-NET-Components-to-COM))

The vb6 application calls the .net COM object (written in C#) and gets an answer. 
But I want to be able to return types like lists  - and the C# compiler doesn't let me.
It throws an error like "generic types are not supported in COM". 
Do you have any advice?

I want to return a list of strings from C# or  a struct

```
    [DispId(1)]
    list<string> GetDay();
```

Comment: Create a non-generic wrapper type around your generic type for each version, and pass those back to COM. This is precisely how C++ Templates work.

Comment: COM doesn't know beans about generic types.  VB6 doesn't either of course.  You can expose ArrayList.  Or your own collection object, as long as it isn't generic.  It doesn't make much sense at all to allow the client code to modify that collection so exposing IEnumerable is surely best.